# AttributeError: Can't pickle local object

Tags: python, pickle, finrl

I'm working on a machine learning university project and I need to save an "agent" (an object) containing some complex stuff that allows me to do other stuff ahahah...I'm using pickle but unfortunately there is an error....AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'constant_fn.<locals>.func'

this is a piece of my code:

```
from finrl.agents.stablebaselines3.models import DRLAgent
import pickle
import os

if os.path.isfile("./filename_pi.obj"):
    print("-FILE FOUND-")
    file_pi = open('filename_pi.obj', 'rb')
    trained_a2c = pickle.load(file_pi)
    file_pi.close()
else:
    print("-FILE NOT FOUND-")
    #A2C
    print("Training A2C model")
    agent = DRLAgent(env=env_train)
    model_a2c = agent.get_model("a2c")
    trained_a2c = agent.train_model(model=model_a2c, tb_log_name="a2c", total_timesteps=50000)
    file_pi = open('filename_pi.obj', 'wb') 
    pickle.dump(trained_a2c, file_pi)
    file_pi.close()
```

Reading similar problems I understood that the problem is in something that is not global, but the problem is that I can not modify anything that is inside **.get_model** and **.train_model** because they are methods of a library not written by me and that I can not touch.
Is there anything I can do? Maybe I don't have to pass "trained_a2c" ? or you recommend me to change the road?

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
from finrl.agents.stablebaselines3.models import DRLAgent
import pickle
import os

if os.path.isfile("./filename_pi.obj"):
    print("-FILE FOUND-")
    file_pi = open('filename_pi.obj', 'rb')
    trained_a2c = pickle.load(file_pi)
    file_pi.close()
else:
    print("-FILE NOT FOUND-")
    #A2C
    print("Training A2C model")
    agent = DRLAgent(env=env_train)
    model_a2c = agent.get_model("a2c")
    trained_a2c = agent.train_model(model=model_a2c, tb_log_name="a2c", total_timesteps=50000)
    file_pi = open('filename_pi.obj', 'wb') 
    pickle.dump(trained_a2c, file_pi)
    file_pi.close()
```

And this for better design:

```
from finrl.agents.stablebaselines3.models import DRLAgent
import pickle
import os

def train_a2c():
    #A2C
    print("Training A2C model")
    agent = DRLAgent(env=env_train)
    model_a2c = agent.get_model("a2c")
    trained_a2c = agent.train_model(model=model_a2c, tb_log_name="a2c", total_timesteps=50000)
    return trained_a2c

if os.path.isfile("./trained_a2c.obj"):
    print("-FILE FOUND-")
    file_pi = open('trained_a2c.obj', 'rb')
    trained_a2c = pickle.load(file_pi)
    file_pi.close()
else:
    print("-FILE NOT FOUND-")
    trained_a2c = train_a2c()
    file_pi = open('trained_a2c.obj', 'wb') 
    pickle.dump(trained_a2c, file_pi) 
    file_pi.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I applied your corrections and the code is now clearer...but the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the the source code of the library, you see how stored models can be loaded and adapt that to your own needs.

Models from stable-baselines3 can be loaded with `modeltype.load(filename)` where `modeltype` is a Model-class from the library, like `A2C`.

also, make sure to use the `save()` method provided from stable_baselines to save a trained model, to make sure it is stored properly. Not sure if just using pickle will achieve the same.

```py
from stable_baselines3 import A2C

filename = "my_a2c_model" # don't have to include .zip extension, if using load()

# loading a trained model from file
model = A2C.load(filename)

# train the model again
agent = DRLAgent(env=env_train)
trained_a2c = agent.train_model(model=model, tb_log_name="a2c", total_timesteps=50000)

# saving the new model with the provided save() method from the library:
trained_a2c.save("my_new_model") # will be saved to my_new_model.zip
```

more information can be found here:

- [Basic Usage: Training, Saving, Loading](https://stable-baselines3.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/examples.html#basic-usage-training-saving-loading)
- [On saving and loading](https://stable-baselines3.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/save_format.html)